# Certbot doesn't find all my domians from Apache config

Tags: lets-encrypt, debian-stretch, certbot

I'm trying to install Lets-encrypt SSL certificate by using certbot.

When typing `certbot` , I get a list of some domains from my apache config, how ever it seems if I have multiple VirtualHosts in a single conf file. then domains are not listed. Is there a fix for this?

I'm using 
**Debian 9**
**Apache2**

Comment: The obvious solution would be to not have multiple VirtualHosts in a single conf file.

Comment: Debian makes it very easy to not have multiple vhosts in a file. Just use the tools the OS offers you.

Comment: Any reason why downvote to this question?

Comment: The config he's describing is completely reasonable. For example one might put http and https vhosts for the same domain in the same file. It'd be nice if certbot would use his config, instead of forcing him to adapt his config to certbot.